# Warning - release not found in protocol

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I created a protocol and a class to use the protocol.

JSTest.h file =

```
@protocol JSTestDelegate

@end

@interface JSTest : NSObject {

    id<JSTestDelegate> delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) id<JSTestDelegate> delegate;

- (id)initWithDelegate:(id<JSTestDelegate>)del;

@end
```

JSTest.m file =

```
#import "JSTest.h"


@implementation JSTest

@synthesize delegate;

- (id)initWithDelegate:(id<JSTestDelegate>)del {

    self = [super init];

    if(self) {

        self.delegate = del;
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {

    [delegate release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

My issue is - in the dealloc method, the

```
[delegate release]
```

gives me a warning

```
-release not found in protocol(s)
```

I am unable to determine the reason. My code should not fail because the delegate will always be a subclass of NSObject. However, I have had bad experiences with warnings that I ignored without understanding the reason for the warning to show up.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a `NSObject` protocol that you can inherit from (reference [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html)). That protocol contains the basic methods of any `NSObject`.

By making your own protocol comply with it, you'll be able to call `-release` without getting any compiler warning.

Sample code:

```
@protocol JSTestDelegate<NSObject>

@end
```

Comment: Followup question then: what advantage does this have over declaring the property NSObject<JS..> * and leaving the inheritance out of the protocol?

Comment: @w.m There is one significant base class in Cocoa/Objective-C besides NSObject: NSProxy (which also conforms to the NSObject protocol). Specifying `NSObject <SomeProtocol> *` unnecessarily restricts NSProxy objects from being used with the API. The vast majority of Cocoa APIs use `id`, not `NSObject *` when they mean "any object". The `id <SomeProtocol>` pattern is just a continuation of the existing pattern.

Comment: I was always wondering about that when stumbling over an id<Protocol>. Thanks for clearing it up!